# is xml & android xml files different?

Tags: xml

I have recently started learning Android Apps & DBMS. There are xml files in Android Apps Project. Prof. started teaching xml in DBMS. I don't know anything about xml. But I need eclips editor for writing xml. I have eclips came with ADT bundle but I am not sure if both xml files are same or different. So I want to know if both of them are same or different in some content.

Comment: Why do you need Eclipse for writing Xml?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are the same, xml files are general in the sense that they can be used by many things for many things, although the structure within the individual XML files would vary depending on the purpose they were created for and their specifications

Answer (score 0):

The difference between XML and Android XML is akin to the difference between the Latin alphabet and the written English language.

The Latin alphabet is a generic means of expressing words. Written English uses the Latin alphabet to express a particular set of words with a commonly agreed meaning.

Any XML editor can handle any XML file, just as any text editor can handle any human language expressed in the Latin alphabet. (And any modern text editor can handle other alphabets too).

Comment: so can I use my ADT eclips to write xml in DBMS course? & Thanks Darth & Quentin